# Converting a CPS file into Java objects

Tags: java, parsing, arrays

I have a CPS (Card Personalization Specification) file used for OTA programming of SIMs, the structure of which looks like this

```
FORMAT_VERSION:01.03
FILE_DATE:20130315150622
FILE_ID:BM00701x
SIMCardDataFormatVersion(03.01)
ConfigurationFile(bell.cfg)
SIMCardData("G&D_America")
{
    CardProfile("BM618039V2.0.0")
    {
        SimVendor(G&D)
        SfmProtocol(03.48_G&D)
        Description("G&D UICC Profile")
        SimApplication(SFM)
        {
        TAR(B00001)
            Version(1.0)
            PID(7F)
            DCS(F6)
            0348Settings(MobileTerminated)
            {
                MaxNumberOfConcatSm(5)
                SPI1(0A)
                SPI2(22)
                CounterStartValue(1)
                KIc(05)
                KID(05)
                PoRSupported(TRUE)
            }
        }
... pruned
```

I want to convert them into a xml file like this

```
<SIMCardData name="G D_America">
<CardProfile name="BM618028V2.1.0">
<SimVendor>G&D</SimVendor> 
<Description>G&D UICC OTA HTTP Profile with applets specified</Description> 
<SimApplication name="USIM">
    <TAR>B00002</TAR> 
    <Version>1.0</Version> 
    <AssociatedSimApplication>SFM</AssociatedSimApplication> 
    <Settings0348>
        <MaxNumberOfConcatSm>5</MaxNumberOfConcatSm> 
        <SPI>0A</SPI> 
        <SPI2>22</SPI2> 
        <CounterStartValue>1</CounterStartValue> 
        <KIc>05</KIc> 
        <KID>05</KID> 
        <PoRSupported>TRUE</PoRSupported> 
    </Settings0348>
```

I read them through the FS provider in JBoss ESB whcih gives the CPS file as a byte array. Is there any package available that lets me parse the bytearray into Java objects from where i can eventually convert it into an xml ?

Comment: I would use a parser generator such as AntLR or JFlex/JavaCUP. AntLR can probably generate code that does the whole transformation for you.

Comment: @aioobe Thanks. AntLR looks promising.